# Send string to database with Ajax not working as intended

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send a simple string to the database. In order to see if I'm half way there, I'm checking to see if $_POST has anything set -- but it doesn't.

Here is my simple form, on an `index.php`:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="add_item" id="add_item">
<input type="button" value="submit" id="button">
</form>
```

And here is the AJAX from that form, where the `success` is triggered:

```
var add_item;
        $('#button').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            add_item = $('#add_item').val();
            console.log(add_item);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'sendData.php',
                data: 'send me!',
                success: function(data){
                    alert('lol');
                }
            });
        });
```

And on the `sendData.php`, but there is nothing in the $_POST global:

```
var_dump($_POST); // returns 0
if (isset($_POST['add_item'])):
    $add_item = $_POST['add_item'];

    $submit = new Connection();
    $submit->connect_db();
    $submit->add_to_DB($add_item);

endif;
```

As you can see, I'm trying to send it to the database; but before that I'm trying to see if anything is in the $_POST global -- but it returns 0.

Would anyone know why? I'm new to this and I can't find any concrete tutorials explaining simply.

Comment: What would you expect to get in `$_POST` when you send `send me!?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting data to something like "testvar=sendme" or simply use a [PlainObject](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#PlainObject)

PHP seems to be expecting key-value-pairs for $_POST to work.

Comment: +1 . However, correcting the code work might be helpful to OP.

Comment: Yes, still getting used to StackOverflow. Since OP for whatever reason was only interested in seeing if there was any POST data at all, I didn't bother to fix all the other flaws and focused on his question.

Comment: Thanks, but 'testvar=sendme' still has nothing in the post global. Is this something I could see by refreshing the sendData.php page, or is this something behind the scenes? For example, if I wanted to retrieve `'name' => 'something'`, what would I send from the AJAX?

Comment: either `data: "name=something"` or `data: {"name":"something"}`